# Scanner class skips over whitespace

Tags: java, arrays

I am using a nested `Scanner` loop to extract the digit from a string line (from a text file) as follows:

```
String str = testString;            
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str); 
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String token = scanner.next();
    // Here each token will be used
}
```

The problem is this code will skip all the spaces `" "`, but I also need to use those "spaces" too. So can `Scanner` return the spaces or I need to use something else?

My text file could contain something like this:

```
0
011
abc
d2d

sdwq

sda
```

Those blank lines contains 1 `" "` each, and those `" "` are what I need returned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Scanner's `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` methods and you'll find your solution since this will allow you to capture empty or white-space lines.

Answer (score 5):

**By default, a scanner uses white space to separate tokens.**

Use [**Scanner#nextLine**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method, Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

> To use a different token separator, invoke useDelimiter(), specifying
>   a regular expression. For example, suppose you wanted the token
>   separator to be a comma, optionally followed by white space. You would
>   invoke,

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
```

Read more from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand what is a *token*. Read the documentation of [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

You could use the [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method to get the whole line and not "ignore" with any whitespace.

Better you could define what is a token by using the [`useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\sample.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String token = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(token);

    }
```

Comment: quick question, what does a blank space equal? null or "" or " " cause I tried to set a loop like if(str == " ") Print("empty") but nothing happened.

Comment: @Herious : `String` comparisons are always done with the use of `equals` and not `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

To use a more funtional approach you could use something like this:

```
String fileContent = new Scanner(new File("D:\\sample.txt"))
            .useDelimiter("")
            .tokens()
            .reduce("", String::concat);
```