# How to include spaces and other chars in line on reading .txt file java

Tags: java

I have 0.txt file which contains: 4 lines which is like this:

```
  
  help 
  hello world
  hello world help
```

And I have code which ignores spaces if I read txt file:

```
public static void Read_With_Spaces(String FileName) {
    File file = new File(FileName);
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
        while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
            String word = fileReader.next();
            System.out.println(word + " " + "health");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need reading with spaces.Please Help Me!

Comment: Can you post what you want the output to be?  Also I recommend following Java naming conventions `Read_With_Spaces` should be `readWithSpaces`, and working on formatting your code better, it will help you debug easier.

Comment: fileReader.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) like `fileReader.hasNextLine()` and then read lines using [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) as in `fileReader.nextLine()`

Comment: Thanks everybody this was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158797/scanner-class-skips-over-whitespace